# how to add object to an object list with different positions xna

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I have already used a for loop to add 22 objects to the list.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    InvadersList.Add(new Invedors (new Vector2(i * 20, 10), Invader));
}
```

Comment: Well, change the value of the position?

Answer (score -1):

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    // Create the list
    List<Invaders> invadersList = new List<Invaders>();

    // Add some objects
    invadersList.Add(new Invader());
    invadersList.Add(new Invader());
    invadersList.Add(new Invader());
    invadersList.Add(new Invader());

    // Insert a new object at position 2
    invadersList.Insert(2, new Invader());
}
```

Comment: is there another way that is easier using for each loop?